# Where is my sqlite database stored in android?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have created a `sqlite` database in android, I can query it inside my code but I cannot find it on the filesystem/sdcard.

I have checked the other SO questions, its NOT in `data/data/package-name...`

I do see a data entry on my app taking up 52kb space, so its there, furthermore when I run the app again it does not trigger a `OnCreate` meaning it already has the DB.

My phone is rooted & I am using a custom jelly bean rom that runs fine for all intents and purposes.

Any ideas where it could be?

CODE c#

```
public class SqliteHelper : SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    private const string DATABASE_NAME = "Book";
    private const int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public SqliteHelper(Context ctx)
    : base(ctx, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION)
{ }

// Method is called during creation of the database
public override void OnCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    db.BeginTransaction();
    try
    {
        db.ExecSQL("CREATE TABLE Chapters (Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Name TEXT NOT NULL);");

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.Put("Name", "1. Family");
        db.Insert("Chapters", null, cv);
        cv.Put("Name", "2. Shopping");
        db.Insert("Chapters", null, cv);
        cv.Put("Name", "3. Work");
        db.Insert("Chapters", null, cv);

        db.SetTransactionSuccessful();
    }
    finally
    {
        db.EndTransaction();
    }

    //if(db.IsOpen())
    //  db.Close();
}
```

Comment: Show us the code where you initialize your Database Connection, that should give us an idea of where your file is stored.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In my rooted phone, it's in :

```
/data/data/<your_app_package_name>/databases/<database_name>
```

Real-life example:

```
/data/data/com.my.package/databases/mydb.db
```

Comment: Coming back to this after some time, I realise you were correct. I was omitting one of the `/data` from the path.

Comment: Coming back to this after some time, I realiseI like your pseudo @لَاإِلٰهَإِلَّاالله :)

Comment: I am not able to see the '/data/data/<your_app_package_name>' anywhere. Do i need to root my phone to see it?

Comment: @anil_pulikoden yes, you should.

Comment: after Marshmellow, the location of database is different. is it true?

Answer (score 11):

1. Go to Tools -> DDMS or click the Device Monitor icon next to SDK Manager in Tool bar.
2. Device Monitor window will open, In File Explorer tab click  data -> data   -> your project name. After that your databases file will open . click "pull a file from device" icon. Save the file using .db extension.
3. open FireFox, Press Alt , Tools->SQLiteManager.
4. Follow Database -> connect to Database -> browse your database file and click ok. Your SQLite file will opened now.

Comment: Agh - I want to love this answer. When I try to expand the `data` folder it won't show anything inside. Do you have to be rooted for this?

Comment: @boltup_im_coding did you ever discover if you have to be rooted for this? I am having same issue

Comment: @wizloc I'm 99% sure you do unless there's a way for Android to know your app is being debugged and it allows you to access just that one folder

Answer (score 8):

It is there. The only reason you can't access it in an Android device is because that folder is private and cannot be seen using conventional methods, the OS protects that folder and that folder (and it's contents e.g. your database) can only be used by that certain application.

If you want to see it, run an emulator, run your application there, go to DDMS view, do to `/data/data/packageName/databases` and it's there. If you don't have access to DDMS, use this ADB Shell command: `$ adb pull /data/data/packageName/databases/yourDBFilename.db`

Answer (score 4):

Calling `Context.getDatabasePath` will give you the definitive answer

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Android Studios, DDMS is in "Tools" - "Android" - "Android Device Monitor".
Use DDMS to find it like how you would have done in Eclipse.

Comment: This works! No need to root the device!

Answer (score 1):

Databases in Android are stored in "data/data/yourPackageName/databases/" by default